# Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details: call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)

Tags: java, r, dll, rjava

I'm trying to install the package - Retip. Downloaded it from GitHub and tries to run it.

I'm receiveing this massage:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Retip':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'D:/BCDD/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'D:/BCDD/Downloads/Retip-master/Retip.Rcheck/Retip'

1 error x | 0 warnings v | 0 notes v
Error: R CMD check found ERRORs
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

I do not know what to do. I tried to install\uninstall 'rJava' a few times.
Also updated for the latest Java version.

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rcdk_3.5.0     rcdklibs_2.3   rJava_0.9-13   devtools_2.3.2 usethis_2.0.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13   magrittr_2.0.1    itertools_0.1-3   fingerprint_3.5.7 pkgload_1.1.0     R6_2.5.0          rlang_0.4.10     
 [8] fastmap_1.0.1     tools_4.0.3       parallel_4.0.3    pkgbuild_1.2.0    png_0.1-7         sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_2.3.0        
[15] withr_2.4.1       iterators_1.0.13  ellipsis_0.3.1    remotes_2.2.0     assertthat_0.2.1  rprojroot_2.0.2   lifecycle_0.2.0  
[22] crayon_1.4.1      processx_3.4.5    purrr_0.3.4       callr_3.5.1       fs_1.5.0          ps_1.5.0          curl_4.3         
[29] testthat_3.0.1    memoise_2.0.0     glue_1.4.2        cachem_1.0.3      compiler_4.0.3    desc_1.2.0        prettyunits_1.1.1
```

My Java version

```
Z:\> java -version
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

Any hint/help will be appreciated

Comment: With regards to your error, it seems you have installed the wrong version of java. It is complaining that it is **not a valid 32-bit**. This indicates that it is expecting a 32-bit system (which is a bit odd). I would assume that it is trying to load java 32-bit while it should actually be loading java 64-bit.

Comment: Try including `INSTALL_opts =  "--no-multiarch"` in your arguments to `install.packages`

Comment: @Oliver - Thank you for pointing this out, Do you have any idea/suggestions how can I force R to use the 64-bit? Many Thanks!

Comment: @SmokeyShakers - Thank you for the advice! It solved the issue :) Thank very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding of why `INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch"` works.   I believe the newer versions of R try to install for both architectures. It's usually not a problem unless your package has system dependencies that only exist on your machine  for one architecture.